# Reset a Login/Pass for an ASP.NET App working with ASP Membership

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have an MS Visual Studio 2010 ASP.NET /SQL SERVER 2008 application with an ASP login authentication, but I don’t have the login/password to sign-in, and when I try to find it in the database I found some   `vw_aspnet_Users` view with the following code:

```
SELECT [ApplicationId]
      ,[UserId]
      ,[UserName]
      ,[LoweredUserName]
      ,[MobileAlias]
      ,[IsAnonymous]
      ,[LastActivityDate]
FROM [my_db].[dbo].[vw_aspnet_Users]
```

Still when I run it, I don’t have a PASSWORD column when I can possibly pick the hashed pass or something!
Sorry I’m new at ASP, but is there a way to have a working login/pass to this, I’m really stuck with this since yesterday!

This is some code of the login page:

ASP:

```
<asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" class="centerBox" Style="width: 100%" OnAuthenticate="Login1_Authenticate"
                OnLoggedIn="Login1_LoggedIn" OnLoggingIn="Login1_LoggingIn">
```

C#:

```
protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
        {
            // Next, determine if the user's username/password are valid
            if (Membership.ValidateUser(Login1.UserName, Login1.Password))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(Login1.UserName, Login1.RememberMeSet);
                e.Authenticated = true;
            } 
            else
            {
                e.Authenticated = false;
                Login1.FailureText = "Wrong Login/Password.";
            }
        }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not get the password from the database. You could find the hash but its hashed to protected the password, so I wouldn't suggest to try to decrypt it.

What you could do: Open **ASP.Net Configuration**: menu: **Website**, click **ASP.Net Configuration** and reset the password or create a new user. You could also temporary remove restrictions to the directory in **Web.Config**.